# Prepared Statement in PHP not binding results

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

When I am trying to get this prepared statement to work I am just testing to get data back it is telling me there is not a matching number of bind_results() from the prepared statement. I cannot figure this our there are three selected elements and three elements in the bind_results();

```
$sql_join_group_data = "SELECT `group_id`, `group`, `group_pass` 
                        FROM `groups` WHERE `group` = 'Knights'";
$stmt4 = $conn->prepare($sql_join_group_data);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($group_id, $group, $group_password);
```

Comment: Is that `$stmt4` code or a typo?

Comment: You don't need prepare/execute since you're not binding any paramenters. That's the point of a prepared statement. You can just do a query and skip the `execute()` all together. `$stmt4 = $conn->query(...); $stmt->bind_result(...);`

Comment: Well I am going to need to have a prepared statement this is just for my testing to make sure its pulling all the correct data before I make it the full prepared statement. But I just missed the $stmt4 after looking over this so many time I must have just kept thinking all those were correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning your statement to `$stmt4` but trying to execute and bind from `$stmt`.

Comment: Wow you have to be kidding me I have been stuck on that for about an hour now! Thank you I think I need some sleep overlooking some thing like that.